# Boxing a reference type (class)?

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, clr, prism, boxing

I have this very simple property (this is a WPF project using Prism Notifications and Interactions)

```
public bool ConfirmNavigation
{
    get { return _confirmNavigation; }
    set { _confirmNavigation = value; base.RaisePropertyChanged<bool>(() => ConfirmNavigation); }
}
```

The IL generated is displayed below. What puzzles me is this line -
 **IL_000a: box MyNamespace.MyClass** 
MyClass is a `class`, *not* a `struct`. What gives?

```
.property instance bool ConfirmNavigation()

.get instance bool MyNamespace.MyClass::get_ConfirmNavigation()
{
    .locals init (
        [0] bool CS$1$0000
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: ldfld bool MyNamespace.MyClass::_confirmNavigation
    IL_0007: stloc.0
    IL_0008: br.s IL_000a

    IL_000a: ldloc.0
    IL_000b: ret
}
.set instance void MyNamespace.MyClass::set_ConfirmNavigation(bool)
{
    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: ldarg.1
    IL_0003: stfld bool MyNamespace.MyClass::_confirmNavigation
    IL_0008: ldarg.0
    IL_0009: ldarg.0
    ***IL_000a: box MyNamespace.MyClass***
    IL_000f: ldtoken MyNamespace.MyClass
    IL_0014: call class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
    IL_0019: call class [System.Core]System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression [System.Core]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression::Constant(object,  class [mscorlib]System.Type)
    IL_001e: ldtoken method instance bool MyNamespace.MyClass::get_ConfirmNavigation()
    IL_0023: call class [mscorlib]System.Reflection.MethodBase [mscorlib]System.Reflection.MethodBase::GetMethodFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeMethodHandle)
    IL_0028: castclass [mscorlib]System.Reflection.MethodInfo
    IL_002d: call class [System.Core]System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression [System.Core]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression::Property(class [System.Core]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression,  class [mscorlib]System.Reflection.MethodInfo)
    IL_0032: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0033: newarr [System.Core]System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression
    IL_0038: call class [System.Core]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<class [mscorlib]System.Func`1<bool>> [System.Core]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression::Lambda<class [mscorlib]System.Func`1<bool>>(class [System.Core]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression,  class [System.Core]System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression[])
    IL_003d: call instance void [Microsoft.Practices.Prism]Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ViewModel.NotificationObject::RaisePropertyChanged<bool>(class [System.Core]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<class [mscorlib]System.Func`1<bool>>)
    IL_0042: nop
    IL_0043: ret
}
```

Comment: This is a side-effect of the compiler generating code for an Expression<>.  It is not illegal.

Comment: Can you explain the motivation behind examining the IL and why it was a problem? What led you here